# (Angular/Typescript) can't use variable to access JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am very confused at the moment. What I am trying to accomplish is very simple. I need to be able to use a variable to access a specific JSON object. I have created a service which imports a JSON file. the app component then uses this service and calls a function printData which takes in the JSON object key of what you want to acesss. The oddest part of this problem is that it works fine on stackblitz!

[Click to see stackblitz] https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-related-project

I have tried the exact same code as above on two local machines and I get the same error!

```
core.js:4081 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at DataServiceService.printData (data-service.service.ts:10)
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:13)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:14)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3913)
    at instantiateRootComponent (core.js:7837)
    at createRootComponent (core.js:18351)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (core.js:22287)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.js:28020)
    at core.js:27731
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Another thing I find odd is that this will work

```
printData() {
    console.log(data['movies'].name);
}
```

but this won't

```
printData() {
    var objectName = 'movies';
    console.log(data[objectName].name);
}
```

I have already added "resolveJsonModule": true and "esModuleInterop": true in the project locally. If anyone can help me I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Locally, what prints in the console when you put just `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Hello Gustavo here is an image of exactly what is shown in the console when I put console.log(data) https://i.ibb.co/FWLgSZV/console.png

Comment: By the image, the 'movies' array is inside a variable called default that's inside a variable called Module, that's why when you call `data[objectName].name`, the error occurs...

Comment: Well how would I go about accessing it then? I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: `data['default']['movies'].name`  or `data.default.movies.name` should work.

Comment: Wow Gustavo that seemed to do the trick! Thank you so much! Would you care to explain however why when I explicitly called 'data['movies'].name' it seemed to work but when i tried to use a variable in place of movies such as 'data[variable].name' it didnt work? Just would like some clarification as to why the second statement requires me to say 'default'?

Comment: It works fine for me like this  console.log(data);
    var name = 'movies'
    console.log(data[name].name)

Comment: got tripped up on this just now as well, maybe obvious but `import { default as data } from '../../my_cool_data.json'` preserves type safety/intellisens while also allowing dynamic property access

Answer (score 0):

```
printData() {
  var objectName = 'movies';
  console.log(data.default[objectName].name); //or data['default'][objectName].name
}
```

Modules are special type of objects, if you console out the imported module you will see the actual values are contained inside the `default` key.

`console.log(data)`

output =
`Module {default: {…}, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}`

You don't, however, need to use the default key if you access the values directly with a string:

```
printData() {
  console.log(data['movies'].name);
}
```